# Can different accounts start Business Objects / Crystal Reports Server 2008 report instances?

Tags: active-directory, crystalreports

I've been tasked with finding domain accounts that need to be removed when the domain goes away.

One of the servers I need to check out is a Crystal Reports Server 2008 R2.

I was wondering if anybody knew if report generation is done just by the account that runs the server, or if it can also be run by other accounts (that also may be domain accounts).